# How to make eventEmitter and socket io friends

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I ran into the problem of infinitely creating event listeners:
There is a socketIo connection handler:
It sets the eventEmitter event handler,
when the event is bubbling, the handler is triggered on everyone connected to the socket

```
async connectionMainNamespace(socket) {
    const {userId} = socket.handshake.query;
    socket.join(userId);

    emitter.addListener('redirectGamePage', (data) => {
      console.log('emmiter');
      socket.to(data.users.black).emit('redirectGamePage', {
        gameId: data.gameId,
        color: 'black'
      });
      socket.to(data.users.white).emit('redirectGamePage', {
        gameId: data.gameId,
        color: 'white'
      });
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    })
  }
```

and emit

```
emitter.emit('redirectGamePage', {
        users: {
          black: game.playerBlack,
          white: game.playerWhite
        },
        gameId
      });
```

I tried to constrain using setMaxListeners function,
but all i get is a warning: MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 2 redirectGamePage listeners added to [EventEmitter]. Use emitter.
setMaxListeners () to increase limit

Answer (score 0):

```
if (emitter.listenerCount('redirectGamePage') < 1) {
      console.log('emitter');
      emitter.on('redirectGamePage', (data) => {
        socket.to(data.users.black).emit('redirectGamePage', {
          gameId: data.gameId,
          color: 'black'
        });
        socket.to(data.users.white).emit('redirectGamePage', {
          gameId: data.gameId,
          color: 'white'
        });
      });
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).